# Error con SUM(). ¿Cómo excluir un campo de la consulta, manteniéndolo en el GROUP BY?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo está consulta

```
SELECT
t.SI_Articulo, 
m.SI_Descripcion,  
t.SI_UM, 
CASE WHEN SI_OV IS NOT NULL THEN '*' ELSE NULL END SI_OV, 
COUNT(DISTINCT t.SI_Ubicacion) SI_Ubicacion, 
SUM(DISTINCT t.SI_Existencia) SI_Existencia, 
SUM(DISTINCT c.SI_Cantidad) SI_Cantidad, 
SUM(DISTINCT c.SI_Cantidad) - SUM(DISTINCT t.SI_Existencia) SI_DIF, 
SUM(DISTINCT c.SI_Cantidad) - SUM(DISTINCT t.SI_Existencia)* m.SI_Costo_Promedio AS SI_Dif_Dinero 
FROM SI_Inventario_Teorico_QAD t 
INNER JOIN SI_Maestro_Ref_QAD m ON m.SI_Num_Articulo = t.SI_Articulo 
INNER JOIN SI_Conteo c ON c.SI_Num_Articulo = t.SI_Articulo
GROUP BY t.SI_Articulo, 
         m.SI_Descripcion, 
         t.SI_UM, 
         c.SI_OV,
         m.SI_Costo_Promedio;
```

la cual me da el siguiente resultado

```
+-------------+----------------+-------+-------+--------------+---------------+-------------+--------+---------------+
| SI_Articulo | SI_Descripcion | SI_UM | SI_OV | SI_Ubicacion | SI_Existencia | SI_Cantidad | SI_DIF | SI_Dif_Dinero |
+-------------+----------------+-------+-------+--------------+---------------+-------------+--------+---------------+
|      013058 | XXXX           | ud    | *     |            1 |             1 |           3 |      2 |         -5657 |
|      200002 | XXXX           | ud    | *     |            5 |            73 |           7 |    -66 |     -15443332 |
|      200002 | XXXX           | ud    | *     |            5 |            73 |          10 |    -63 |     -15443329 |
+-------------+----------------+-------+-------+--------------+---------------+-------------+--------+---------------+
```

El error está en que no se está sumando la cantidad de la misma referencia `200002`, ya que no tienen la misma (`SI_OV`), entonces la separa, pero si comento esta linea

```
CASE WHEN SI_OV IS NOT NULL THEN '*' ELSE NULL END SI_OV
```

y comento también la del  `GROUP BY c.SI_OV`, sí me hace la suma.

¿Alguna forma de decirle que al sumar me ignore `SI_OV` pero lo incluya como condición de agregación?

Comment: si, sacandola como dijiste.. a que te refieres con ignorarla?

Comment: Si saco  `c.SI_OV` del GROUP BY me da un error

Comment: que error? donde?

Comment: `La columna 'SI_Conteo.SI_OV' de la lista de selección no es válida, porque no está contenida en una función de agregado ni en la cláusula GROUP BY`

Comment: claro, si la sacas del group by no puede estar en un case.. SQL es matematica, cual esperas que sea el resultado obtenido si sacas esa columna del group by? pq si siempre viene distinto, ninguna base va a saber que hacer con ese valor...

Comment: Alguna forma de que la SI_OV,  no me interfiera en la suma de la cantidad? ya que como explico arriba cuando un mismo articulo tienen diferente SI_OV no me suma la cantidad.

Comment: deberias sacarlo de todos lados. si no te sirve su valor, para que lo muestras en el query?

Comment: por que si tiene SI_OV debo de poner un `*`

Comment: Esto es muy sencillo, simplemente debes reemplazar `c.SI_OV` en el `GROUP BY` por la expresión `CASE`: `CASE WHEN SI_OV IS NOT NULL THEN '*' ELSE NULL END`

Comment: @Lamak  Muchas gracias. está funcionando.

Comment: bueno parece que ya tiene respuesta, Simplemente no entendia el resultado que querias llegar a obtener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que usar la columna `c.SI_OV` en el `GROUP BY` te está entregando este resultado. Lo que tienes que hacer en este caso es usar la expresión `CASE` en el `GROUP BY` en vez de la columna:

```
GROUP BY t.SI_Articulo, 
         m.SI_Descripcion, 
         t.SI_UM, 
         CASE WHEN SI_OV IS NOT NULL THEN '*' ELSE NULL END,
         m.SI_Costo_Promedio;
```

De todas formas te recomiendo que revises el uso de la columna `m.SI_Costo_Promedio` directamente en la multiplicación, sin pasar por una función de agregación (puede ser que esté bien, pero a simple viste parece sospechoso)